# Deserializing JSON to a class containing a dynamic property with System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

The objective is to deserialize a JSON response to a wrapper response class containing a dynamic part, using the new **System.Text.Json** library from **NET Core 3**.

That is

```
{
    "fixedProperty": "Hello",
    "dynamicProperty": { 
        "attributeOne": "One",
        "attributeTwo": "Two",
    }
}
```

to

```
public class MyResponseClass
{
    public string FixedProperty { get; set; }
    public dynamic DynamicProperty { get; set; }  
}

// Where the dynamic property is one of the classes.
// (MyDataClassOne in the particular JSON example above)
public class MyDataClassOne
{
    public string AttributeOne { get; set; }
    public string AttributeTwo { get; set; }  
}

public class MyDataClassTwo
{
    public string AttributeThree { get; set; }
    public string AttributeFour { get; set; }  
}

...
```

The type of the dynamic property in the response is always known in advance (depends on the request), and is one of, say, three different classes.

Could not figure out a clean way to do so, except for not having one wrapper class with a dynamic property but multiple distinct response classes for each of the cases (which obviously works fine but is not the desired solution).

EDIT: 
**The solution was to use a generic.**

Comment: Well what is the point of JSON if it is not predictable?  Anyways you could have all possible properties in a single class and then process based on which properties are not null for example....  Also if you are in control of the JSON then maybe you should define a better strategy for your model and have specific api actions return specific JSON models.

Comment: Maybe if you explain better what the application does and what your ultimate goal is we could try to figure out a better way to achieve what you need,

Comment: I am consuming an API that i have no control over. All responses from that API are, of course, predictable. All the responses have the same outer structure and a data attribute that is different for each endpoint. This is my attempt at factoring out the common part of a response as an exercise, i'm teaching myself c#. As i said, creating a separate model for each response works perfectly fine, but i am looking for a way to factor out the common outer shell.

Comment: Since you always know the type of `dynamicProperty` in advance, why not use a generic?  `public class MyResponseClass<T>
{
    public string FixedProperty { get; set; }
    public T DynamicProperty { get; set; }  
}`

Comment: Yes, this would have been perfect for my case if it worked. For some reason the DynamicProperty stays empty if deserialized this way and i can not figure out why. Is deserializing to a generic type supported?

Comment: Scratch that, i had a typo in my code. This works perfectly, thank you so very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since *the type of the dynamic property in the response is always known in advance (depends on the request)*, you can use a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) root object:

```
public class MyResponseClass<T> 
{ 
    public string FixedProperty { get; set; } 
    public T DynamicProperty { get; set; } 
}
```

And then declare `T` to be whatever known concrete class is required, e.g.

```
var root = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyResponseClass<MyDataClassOne>>(responseString);
var fixedProperty = root.fixedProperty;
var attributeOne = root.DynamicProperty?.AttributeOne;
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```cs
var myResponseClass = new MyResponseClass();

dynamic myClass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>("{\"fixedProperty\":\"Hello\",\"dynamicProperty\": {\"attributeOne\":\"One\",\"attributeTwo\":\"Two\"}}");
dynamic myProperty = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpandoObject>(myClass.dynamicProperty.ToString());

myResponseClass.FixedProperty = myClass.fixedProperty.ToString();
myResponseClass.DynamicProperty = myProperty;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Although using a generic type fit my scenario better, this actually answered another question that i was meaning to ask! Thanks.